# Drop rows where a certain column has more than n zeros in a row

Tags: python, pandas

I am processing data from a datalogger which collects data at millisecond intervals, regardless of whether anything interesting is happening. As a result, there are long stretches of data where certain columns are zero. I would like to drop these rows, but leave some number of them as padding, which will help in further processing.

Example input:

```
a b c
1 2 3
0 3 2
0 1 0
0 3 7
0 9 6
4 0 1
0 2 5
0 6 3
0 1 6
```

Example output - filter on column `a`, replace column with more than 2 zero rows with exactly 2 zero rows (selection of which rows to drop can be arbitrary):

```
a b c
1 2 3
0 3 2
0 1 0
4 0 1
0 2 5
0 6 3
```

My current code drops all rows where a column is zero:

```
df= df[df['ColName'] != 0]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a rolling (n+1) sum to exclude the rows you wouldn't like to keep. For example for two consecutive 0s you can use:

```
exclude = df['a'].rolling(3).sum() != 0
```

And then:

```
output = df.loc[exclude,:]
```

Returning:

```
   a  b  c
0  1  2  3
1  0  3  2
2  0  1  0
5  4  0  1
6  0  2  5
7  0  6  3
```

Or, in a one-liner:

```
output = df[df['a'].rolling(3).sum() != 0]
```

You can change the number in the rolling function to fit the amount of periods you'd like to check.

Comment: My values are actually floats, and this doesn't seem to work for floats. I get `KeyError: "None of [Float64Index([nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,\n              ...\n              0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],\n             dtype='float64', length=174532)] are in the [columns]"`

Comment: What about when the first row has a zero?

Comment: You  have a very strange index then. Do you actually need to have so many nulls and 0s? Otherwise you can just use `reset_index()`